# IllegalStateException Activity has been destroyed - Triple-nested Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, illegalstateexception, android-nested-fragment, fragmentmanager

I have a `Fragment`, let's call it... `F1` containing a `Fragment` `F2`; which in turn contains a `Fragment` `F3`.

When I launch my application I receive this error:

```
IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
```

which refers to this line of code:

```
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentcontainer, fragment_profile_list.newInstance()).commit();
```

Where `fragmentcontainer` is a `FrameLayout` within my primary upper level `Fragment` `F1`. Where `F2` is placed within `F1`'s `fragmentcontainer`.

Any ideas on how to go about solving this; I tried doing a search and the other results said to hardcode a `Fragment` field and allocate it immediately but that did not resolve the matter either.

Comment: Is it possible you're doing this before you call through to super.onCreate()?

Comment: I'm sorry; how do you mean exactly?

Comment: Where are you committing that transaction?

Comment: Within the onCreateView of F2

Comment: Remember this a triple-nested fragment. So F3 is in F2 are in F1.

Comment: Might be a quirk of the level of nesting (nested fragments definitely have some issues). Try committing the transaction in onActivityCreated().

Comment: Tried moving it to the onActivityCreated() within my F2 implementation; same error.

Comment: Also; if I just erase it entirely I get a "IllegalStateException" No Activity error

Comment: Unfortunately, I have a feeling that the support library just isn't designed to go that deeply nested. The FragmentActivity calls through to the FragmentManager to notify that the state is not saved in onCreate(), onStart(), and onResume(); I have a feeling that the FragmentManager then notifies the immediate child FragmentManager as well, but doesn't do this recursively.

Comment: I could be wrong (and I hope so) but without digging through the source ([here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v4/) if you're interested) it's hard to say for sure. I've never done nesting more than two deep.

Comment: I can construct around this thanks for the information :)

Answer (score 1):

You can dump the internal state of F2 before adding F3. If you see mActivity != null it will be fine. Otherwise you will get the exception.

```
dump("", null,  new PrintWriter(System.out, true), null);
```

I am not sure what made mActivity = null in your case. In my case, I called the fragment's getChildFragmentManger too early before the fragment was attached (when mActivity = null). 
When it is called for the first time, getChildFragmentManager internally initializes mChildFragmentManager for the fragment. As result, I ended up with a mChildFragmentManager with a null mActivity. Later when I tried to use it to add a child fragment, I got the 'Activity has been destroyed' exception.